# Comparing Databases/Tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

Let's say I have two databases: one contains a list of `books` which are in my possession, the other contains a list of all `allowed_books` which are allowed by the government to be in my possession (okay, perhaps a bad example, but you'll get the idea soon). The `allowed_books` database is constant and consistent. If a `Book` in my `books` database isn't also in the `allowed_books` database, I need to delete it from `books`.

What is the best way to do this?

Is there a Rails/Sqlite function/method that will compare two databases and remove extraneous entries? Or do I have to do this somewhat manually?

I was thinking that before I actually create a new `Book`, I'll run something like `AllowedBook.find_by_name(book_name)` on it first. If it returns nil, then I won't add it in the first place. Or if, as stated above, Rails/Sqlite has some default way to check for inconsistencies between databases, is this a better option?

I'm fairly certain I can do it manually using `find_by_name`, but is this the best option?

Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6, SQLite3 3.6.20.

Thanks!

Comment: This may help: http://www.sql-server-tool.com/compare-two-tables.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean "two tables", not "two databases". There is no way to do what you suggest in either Rails or Sqlite. You have to do it manually.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Just implemented the code, it actually runs faster than inserting everything. Wasn't expecting that, thus the question. Thanks!